# How to get/read and match iOS Device attributions from Safari and native app

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios9, mobile-safari, fingerprint

Can you please help me on `iOS` device attribution (fingerprinting) from `Safari` app and inside the our native app. I have requirement like we have to reward some points when the customer installs and sign up for our `iOS` app (only first time installs). The app link will be shared through Message, Email and social media apps and here the app installed person gets some 1x points and link shared person gets 2x points.

So, I should get to know who shared the this link to reward him once the customer has installed the app.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use the [advertisement identifier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/adsupport/asidentifiermanager). Since Apple disallows you to get any unique device identifiers.

You will have to reroute all installs thru your own server, this is where you link the advertisement identifier to an user. Then redirect the use to the AppStore. After install you sent the advertisement identifier to your server where you can look it up and assign the points.

It will not be fool prove but it is the best you will get, AdMob uses this to track installs via their ads.

Comment: Sounds good, but now we have option to disable "Limit Ad Tracking" from settings in iOS 10, when a user disable it the OS will send value of “00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000”.

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. But Apple put users privacy before developer convenience. Thus you will have to deal with it.

Comment: Yes, I got stuck here only. I want to know the procedure if user disable "Limit Ad Tracking".